# An app like CCleaner that works on external / non-system drives?

Tags: windows

I have been hunting for an app or set of scripts that will perform cruft cleanup (remove junk files; clean temp folders; browser caches; etc.) on drives that are not in an active system.  So far all that I've evaluated only work on an active system.  Does such a utility exist or do I have to write my own set of scripts?

Comment: Do those drives contain an actual OS, or do they just contain a bunch of (random) files?

Comment: This is an OS installation drive; just not in the normally booting computer.  This is a cleanup situation where it's handy to scrub them down before running av and antimalware software.

Comment: That makes things a whole lot easier, 'cuz if they didn't contain an OS it would be nearly impossible

Answer (score 1):

Although I am hesitant to actually recommend it (CCleaner is dangerous and 99% useless)

CCleaner does have an [Enterprise Edition](http://www.piriform.com/business/ccleaner-network-edition) which allows you to work with machines across your network.

Answer (score 0):

Another app that seems to do this fairly well that I've been playing with is [CleanUp!](http://www.stevengould.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=15&Itemid=69)  I'm not yet sure how effective it is on newer Windows OS releases, but it seems to have some real potential as it offers a preview run as well.

**Usage**:

[image: screenshot]

**Options**:

[image: options]